# Fail2Ban does not ban failed root login attempt

Tags: linux, firewalls, ssh

I have a small server which only open ports are ssh, http and https. I have fail2ban installed and set up so that after 3 failed attempts someone gets blocked for 10 minutes (thats the dafault I think).

root login is disabled but people trying to access it don't get blocked.

`cat /var/log/messages | grep ssh` shows like 50 such attempts:

```
Jan 20 10:50:57 localhost sshd[28666]: SSH: Server;Ltype: Version;Remote: 88.190.31.135-57382;Protocol: 2.0;Client: libssh-0.1
Jan 20 10:50:57 localhost sshd[28666]: SSH: Server;Ltype: Kex;Remote: 88.190.31.135-57382;Enc: aes128-cbc;MAC: hmac-sha1;Comp: none [preauth]
Jan 20 10:50:57 localhost sshd[28666]: SSH: Server;Ltype: Authname;Remote: 88.190.31.135-57382;Name: root [preauth]
Jan 20 10:50:57 localhost sshd[28666]: Received disconnect from 88.190.31.135: 11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Jan 20 10:50:57 localhost sshd[28668]: SSH: Server;Ltype: Version;Remote: 88.190.31.135-57437;Protocol: 2.0;Client: libssh-0.1
Jan 20 10:50:57 localhost sshd[28668]: SSH: Server;Ltype: Kex;Remote: 88.190.31.135-57437;Enc: aes128-cbc;MAC: hmac-sha1;Comp: none [preauth]
Jan 20 10:50:57 localhost sshd[28668]: SSH: Server;Ltype: Authname;Remote: 88.190.31.135-57437;Name: root [preauth]
Jan 20 10:50:57 localhost sshd[28668]: Received disconnect from 88.190.31.135: 11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Jan 20 10:50:57 localhost sshd[28670]: SSH: Server;Ltype: Version;Remote: 88.190.31.135-57515;Protocol: 2.0;Client: libssh-0.1
Jan 20 10:50:57 localhost sshd[28670]: SSH: Server;Ltype: Kex;Remote: 88.190.31.135-57515;Enc: aes128-cbc;MAC: hmac-sha1;Comp: none [preauth]
Jan 20 10:50:58 localhost sshd[28670]: SSH: Server;Ltype: Authname;Remote: 88.190.31.135-57515;Name: root [preauth]
Jan 20 10:50:58 localhost sshd[28670]: Received disconnect from 88.190.31.135: 11: Bye Bye [preauth]
```

After this he tried another user, Oracle, which doesn't even exist:

```
Jan 20 10:50:58 localhost sshd[28672]: SSH: Server;Ltype: Version;Remote: 88.190.31.135-57584;Protocol: 2.0;Client: libssh-0.1
Jan 20 10:50:58 localhost sshd[28672]: SSH: Server;Ltype: Kex;Remote: 88.190.31.135-57584;Enc: aes128-cbc;MAC: hmac-sha1;Comp: none [preauth]
Jan 20 10:50:58 localhost sshd[28672]: SSH: Server;Ltype: Authname;Remote: 88.190.31.135-57584;Name: oracle [preauth]
Jan 20 10:50:58 localhost sshd[28672]: Invalid user oracle from 88.190.31.135
Jan 20 10:50:58 localhost sshd[28672]: input_userauth_request: invalid user oracle [preauth]
Jan 20 10:50:58 localhost sshd[28672]: pam_tally2(sshd:auth): pam_get_uid; no such user
Jan 20 10:50:58 localhost sshd[28672]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Jan 20 10:50:58 localhost sshd[28672]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=sd-32510.dedibox.fr
Jan 20 10:51:00 localhost sshd[28672]: Failed password for invalid user oracle from 88.190.31.135 port 57584 ssh2
Jan 20 10:51:00 localhost sshd[28672]: Received disconnect from 88.190.31.135: 11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Jan 20 10:51:00 localhost sshd[28674]: SSH: Server;Ltype: Version;Remote: 88.190.31.135-58021;Protocol: 2.0;Client: libssh-0.1
Jan 20 10:51:00 localhost sshd[28674]: SSH: Server;Ltype: Kex;Remote: 88.190.31.135-58021;Enc: aes128-cbc;MAC: hmac-sha1;Comp: none [preauth]
Jan 20 10:51:00 localhost sshd[28674]: SSH: Server;Ltype: Authname;Remote: 88.190.31.135-58021;Name: oracle [preauth]
Jan 20 10:51:00 localhost sshd[28674]: Invalid user oracle from 88.190.31.135
Jan 20 10:51:00 localhost sshd[28674]: input_userauth_request: invalid user oracle [preauth]
Jan 20 10:51:00 localhost sshd[28674]: pam_tally2(sshd:auth): pam_get_uid; no such user
Jan 20 10:51:00 localhost sshd[28674]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Jan 20 10:51:00 localhost sshd[28674]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=sd-32510.dedibox.fr
Jan 20 10:51:02 localhost sshd[28674]: Failed password for invalid user oracle from 88.190.31.135 port 58021 ssh2
Jan 20 10:51:02 localhost sshd[28674]: Received disconnect from 88.190.31.135: 11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Jan 20 10:51:02 localhost sshd[28676]: SSH: Server;Ltype: Version;Remote: 88.190.31.135-59203;Protocol: 2.0;Client: libssh-0.1
Jan 20 10:51:02 localhost sshd[28676]: SSH: Server;Ltype: Kex;Remote: 88.190.31.135-59203;Enc: aes128-cbc;MAC: hmac-sha1;Comp: none [preauth]
Jan 20 10:51:03 localhost sshd[28676]: SSH: Server;Ltype: Authname;Remote: 88.190.31.135-59203;Name: oracle [preauth]
Jan 20 10:51:03 localhost sshd[28676]: Invalid user oracle from 88.190.31.135
Jan 20 10:51:03 localhost sshd[28676]: input_userauth_request: invalid user oracle [preauth]
Jan 20 10:51:03 localhost sshd[28676]: pam_tally2(sshd:auth): pam_get_uid; no such user
Jan 20 10:51:03 localhost sshd[28676]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Jan 20 10:51:03 localhost sshd[28676]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=sd-32510.dedibox.fr
Jan 20 10:51:04 localhost sshd[28676]: Failed password for invalid user oracle from 88.190.31.135 port 59203 ssh2
Jan 20 10:51:04 localhost sshd[28676]: Received disconnect from 88.190.31.135: 11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Jan 20 10:51:04 localhost sshd[28678]: SSH: Server;Ltype: Version;Remote: 88.190.31.135-59651;Protocol: 2.0;Client: libssh-0.1
Jan 20 10:51:04 localhost sshd[28678]: SSH: Server;Ltype: Kex;Remote: 88.190.31.135-59651;Enc: aes128-cbc;MAC: hmac-sha1;Comp: none [preauth]
```

After that: `/var/log/fail2ban`

```
2012-01-20 10:51:04,701 fail2ban.actions: WARNING [ssh-iptables] Ban 88.190.31.135
```

I wonder why this didn't happen as he tried to access my server with the root account? I bet there is a way to change fail2bans behaviour here, but how?

system info, in case needed: gentoo 3.2.0, openssh 5.9, iptables-1.4.12.1, fail2ban-0.8.6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your second example, you'll see `authentication failure`, and that's what Fail2Ban was keying in on.

As an example of the current fresh-install config on Ubuntu (/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/sshd.conf:

```
failregex = ^%(__prefix_line)s(?:error: PAM: )?Authentication failure for .* from <HOST>\s*$
        ^%(__prefix_line)s(?:error: PAM: )?User not known to the underlying authentication module for .* from <HOST>\s*$
        ^%(__prefix_line)sFailed (?:password|publickey) for .* from <HOST>(?: port \d*)?(?: ssh\d*)?$
        ^%(__prefix_line)sROOT LOGIN REFUSED.* FROM <HOST>\s*$
        ^%(__prefix_line)s[iI](?:llegal|nvalid) user .* from <HOST>\s*$
        ^%(__prefix_line)sUser .+ from <HOST> not allowed because not listed in AllowUsers$
        ^%(__prefix_line)sauthentication failure; logname=\S* uid=\S* euid=\S* tty=\S* ruser=\S* rhost=<HOST>(?:\s+user=.*)?\s*$
        ^%(__prefix_line)srefused connect from \S+ \(<HOST>\)\s*$
        ^%(__prefix_line)sAddress <HOST> .* POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!*\s*$
        ^%(__prefix_line)sUser .+ from <HOST> not allowed because none of user's groups are listed in AllowGroups\s*$
```

If you want to get rid of the root account attempts, you'll have to add a line that matches a line from root logins.

```
Jan 20 10:50:57 localhost sshd[28668]: SSH: Server;Ltype: Authname;Remote: 88.190.31.135-57437;Name: root [preauth]
Jan 20 10:50:57 localhost sshd[28668]: Received disconnect from 88.190.31.135: 11: Bye Bye [preauth]
```

Format a regex to match one of those lines -- either any time somebody tries to authenticate as root or any time somebody disconnects during pre-auth.

Example:

```
^%(__prefix_line)s.+Name: root \[preauth\]\s*$
```

Comment: I figured out a workaround, I just tried to match the last line. I added a user `ssh` and added all users allowed to login remotely to that group and further added a line `AllowGroups ssh` to `sshd_config`. All users not in that group now trigger the line `not listed in AllowGroups`.

Comment: @WalterMaier-Murdnelch you could also configure a whitelist of users who can ssh into your server in the ssh configuration, and then add another rule to the fail2ban regex banning "not allowed because not listed in AllowUsers".

Comment: I've noticed that in my `/var/log/secure` log I also had lots of lines like in the question reading Jan 20 10:51:04 localhost sshd[28676]: Received disconnect from 88.190.31.135: 11: Bye Bye [preauth] But without any other lines mentioning the same IP, so in the `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/sshd.conf` file I added a filter reading ^%(__prefix_line)sReceived disconnect from <HOST>: 11: Bye Bye\s*$